# Root directory on 14.0.4

Tags: root

i am a newbie with ubuntu 14.0.4 desktop platform just installed it on my oracle virtual box. can't seem to be able enter my root directory. 
Any help please.

Comment: did you try cd ~

Comment: or `cd /` if you truly mean the root

Answer (score 1):

If you try to open it from Nautilus file manager, root is labeled as a Computer in Places sidebar. Or, in Terminal you can use a cd command to change directory:

```
cd /
```

"/" is a root directory on Linux.